# How can I select multiple values from a select dropdown and rank them based on the order they were selected in?

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a multiple select dropdown which lets you pick multiple values(two in my case) and ranks them based on the order you selected them in.

Comment: Then what did you try?

Comment: Have you already tried something? Please read [ask].

Comment: Please show us what you have tried and your Html code.

Comment: Actually what I have right now is two distinct dropdowns as primary user and secondary user.
I am curious if I can do that in a single multiple select dropdown where I can select 2 users, the first one as primary and the second one as secondary

Comment: Using just a multi-`select` would not be good UX.  The user would not know (without extension instruction) that the first would be primary.   As a user, I would likely click them in the order they appear in the list (especially if one is near the top, I wouldn't go to the bottom then scroll back to where I was).  Also consider changing mind and mis-clicks.   Click B,F (B primary) - oh wait, it's not B, it's C - unclick B, click C - now F is primary not C.  This is not good UX.

Comment: Using just `<select multiple>` this would not be possible.  You can shift-click to select multiple values - which is first/second?  You can select *multiple* values (not just 2) - what do you do about the others?  Clicking without shift/control (for multi) is not intuitive for normal/non-technical/the "average" user so they'll click once then click again and first will be unselected.  You can use an array to store what was clicked, in the order it was clicked, but this would not give you what you're hoping for.  You *could* use **a custom control**, just **not** a `<select multiple>`

Comment: Thats fair but what if we show numbers and other things? (thing is, my employer wants it. I've already tried to explain them but its not working)

Moreover, UX apart, is that even possible?

Comment: @freedomn-m
Fair enough, Thanks a lot for helping me out! :)

Comment: "*my employer wants it*" - do they? are you sure?  They've *explicitly* asked for you to combine two drop downs into a `<select multiple>`?  Or, more likely, they asked you to combine the two drop downs **"into a single drop down"** (hint: this is not the same, it's a business requirement, not a technical solution).     Yes, it's more work than just stuffing "multiple" into a select, but this could create a better UX if done correctly - just not with `<select multiple>`.  (note: I'm not berating you for asking the question - it might have been possible, and could have saved you a lot of time)

Comment: They just want it to happen in a single dropdown. (Since we have less space remaining on the form) I got curious about this and started digging deeper.
Other thin I can do is just add two dropdowns in a single dropdown, that would be neater and easier to use but I just wanted to know.

Comment: Use this: https://select2.org/selections#limiting-the-number-of-selections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
  $(document).ready(function () {
    var first = '';
    var second = '';
    var flag = 0;     

    $('button').click(function () {
        var x = $('select').val();
        first = x[x.length - 2];
        second = x[x.length - 1];
       alert('first:' + first +'----Second:' + second);      

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html><head>       
</head><body>
<select name="test" multiple>
    <option>123</option>
    <option>456</option>
    <option>789</option>
     <option>110</option>
    <option>220</option>    
</select>
<button>Show</button>
</body></html>
```

Try this one...

Comment: Control-Clicked 456 then 789 then 110 - select shows all 3 selected, alert says I clicked 789 first and 110 second.  Could add a check that >2 have been selected.

Comment: Moused-down on 456, dragged to bottom to multiple-select - select shows 4 items selected, alert says I haven't selected anything at all.

Comment: @ freedomn-m sir,I just try for this specific scenario only, for >2 need to implement array.

Comment: No, you miss my point - the user *can* select more than 2 and your code handles this scenario incorrectly.  It's not that OP want's more than 2, then explicitly want 2 (as you've provided, so that is correct).  Just your code gives the *wrong* 2.

Answer (score 0):

This wouldn't be possible with normal UI elements, but maybe you could create something of a drag and drop system? I use Sortable (https://github.com/SortableJS/Sortable) in one of my websites, and I really like it. If you feel like you have propper experience in HTML, CSS and Javascript/jQuery, maybe this could be a fun challenge?